# Firebase Recycler Adapter showing Error

Tags: android, firebase

> Variable 'viewholder','postion'& model is accesssed from with inner class it need to be declare final, but when i make it final it shows error in adapter.I am using Firebase 11.2.0 Please help me

[image]

```
 private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {
        adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>()
 {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder,int position, @NonNull  Food model) {
                viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                viewHolder.food_price.setText(String.format(" Rs. %s", model.getPrice().toString()));

                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);
                //ADD FAvorites
                if (localdb.isFavorite(adapter.getRef(position).getKey()))
                    viewHolder.fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                //Click to change favorite state
                viewHolder.fav_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (!localdb.isFavorite(adapter.getRef(position).getKey()))
                        {
                            localdb.addToFavorites(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                            viewHolder.fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                            Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + model.getName() + "was Added To Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            localdb.removeFromFavorites(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                            viewHolder.fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                            Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + model.getName() + " was Removed From Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try to make `FoodViewHolder` final too in the second line of the function.

Comment: not working,getting error

Answer (score 0):

You need to send *firebase* option in this method.

because of constructor like this in `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Refer below code for more details:

```
public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<T> options) {
    mSnapshots = options.getSnapshots();

    if (options.getOwner() != null) {
        options.getOwner().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }
}
```

Refer [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) too.

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare position to final use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` it will return the position.

For `ViewHolder` move your setOnClickListener to `ViewHolder` class

```
private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {
        adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>()
    {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder,int position, @NonNull  Food model) {
                viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                viewHolder.food_price.setText(String.format(" Rs. %s", model.getPrice().toString()));


                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);
                //ADD FAvorites
                if (localdb.isFavorite(adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey()))
                    viewHolder.fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
            }
    }
}


 class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        ImageView fav_image;


        FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fav_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_image);

            fav_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (!localdb.isFavorite(adapter.getRef(getAdapterPosition()).getKey()))
                        {
                            localdb.addToFavorites(adapter.getRef(getAdapterPosition()).getKey());
                            fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                            Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + model.getName() + "was Added To Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            localdb.removeFromFavorites(adapter.getRef(getAdapterPosition()).getKey());
                            fav_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                            Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + model.getName() + " was Removed From Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: ok, but what about viewholder & model variables when i make it final it shows error in adapter FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food>)
in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied
to
()

Comment: @amol junghare can you please add you `FoodViewHolder` class i will update code

Comment: @amol junghare i have updated by answer